# nHibernate HQL dynamic Instantiation question

Tags: vb.net, nhibernate, hql

I can't find what's going on with the following nHibernate HQL.

here's my VB.Net code:

```
Return _Session.GetNamedQuery("PersonAnthroSummary").SetInt32(0, 2).UniqueResult()
```

My Named Query:

```
<sql-query name="PersonAnthroSummary">
           select New PersonAnthroSummary( Anthro.Height, Anthro.Weight ) from PersonAnthroContact as Anthro where Anthro.ID = ? 
  </sql-query>
```

and i am importing the DTO class:

```
<import class="xxxxxxx.DataServices.PersonAnthroSummary, xxxxxxx.DataServices"/>
```

PersonAnthroSummary has a constructor that will take height and weight arguments.

when i test this, nHibernate throwing following exception:

```
{"Incorrect syntax near 'Anthro'."}
```

and generated QueryString is:

```
"select New PersonAnthroSummary( Anthro.Height, Anthro.Weight ) from PersonAnthroContact as Anthro where Anthro.ID = @p0"
```

Can some one tell me what i'm doing wrong here?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. actual problem with my DTO class PersonAnthroSummary, which has a constructor that takes arguments of type decimal. but PersonAnthroContact mapping, those 2 columns mapped to dirrefent types. i changed PersonAnthroSummary constructor to take those types instead of decimals , then its working....

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring it as a SQL query instead of a HQL query.

The element name should be `<query>`.

Comment: I changed it from <sql-query .../> to <query .../>, now i am getting this exception: "Errors in named queries: {PersonAnthroSummary}".  thanks for your responce.

Comment: Hello Diego, i tried new insteadof New, but i am getting same error.. is thr anyway to know actual problem ..insteadof this not friendly message...